# Advanced Ajax Page Loader change body class

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, loader

I am using Advanced Ajax Page Loader Wordpress plugin on my Wordpress installation and its SEVERELY lacking documentation.

This is a question directed at people who worked with it in the past, how do I get to change my body class, I see a hint at using jQuery(dataa) but this doesn't help me at all, I did a console.log of that item and I don't know exactly how to search through that data to get the body class of the current page I am in, once I got it I can change easily my body class but I don't know exactly how to select it.

I tried putting this

```
console.log(jQuery(dataa).find('body'))

if (jQuery(dataa).find('body')) {
console.log('yeaaa'); } else {
console.log('neeeyyy') }
```

in the admin http://screencast.com/t/qfqmrhqhrw but I get no response on my site.

Comment: dataa is simply a jquery object storing reference to the DOM element that was loaded. `find` is used to target the body element, from there, you can get the class by doing `jQuery(dataa).find('body').prop('class')`. If the body has more than one class, then you will get a string. If you need individual classes, you will need to do `var myVar = jquery(dataa).find('body').split(' ')`. where `myVar` will now be an array where you can get the individual class names like `myVar[0]` and `myVar[1]`..etc.... (note, prop is jQuery 1.7+, if you are using less than 1.7, then use .attr()).

Answer (score -4):

I am the plugin author!

There is plenty of documentation and more can be added as I help people and become aware of what stuff I should give information about. For instance I have a growing database of "reload codes" for supporting various javascript codes.

You change your body class in the AAPL setting page, do not edit the main scripts! This is assuming you have the latest version of AAPL which you should fetch now form the link below before messing with anything.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

Also start a support request on that site as you are more likely to get relevant help.

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to find that documentation we're talking about, would you please provide some links, the code pasted above was entered in administration.